# Constant bumping noise

Tags: noise

We have a radon pump, a sump pump and a weeping system.  There is a constant bumping like someone is hammering on the outside wall.  We tracked it down to the inside corner of the house near the weeping system.  we cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: No clue. All I can suggest is a trick from Car Talk: Stick one end of a rubber tube in your ear and use the other end as a stethoscope to try to narrow down more precisely where the noise is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

This might very well be [water hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_hammer), where liquid alternates gas it will 'hammer' into any curves and can make noise. Have you tried turning of all powered devices by just flipping the main switch? Does it still make noise then? Try to eliminate all possible sources one by one. It might just be a faulty bearing in one of the pumps. Are there any other constructions near the building where the noise could come from?

This is not really an answer, but you didn't really ask a question either. If I was able to comment on this SE, this would have been a comment.